# How do I find multiple items in a field with mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following type of occurrence in my Mongo documents.

```
"tags" : [ [ "narnia" ], [ "aslan" ], [ "winter" ], [ "heaven" ] ]
```

I need to know how to find this document by matching all of any number of the tags. I.e. Narnia AND Aslan (but not Narnia OR Aslan).

The query needs to be made with in PHP.

So far I only have it working for a single tag. I.e.

```
$filter['tags'] = array('$in' => array(array('Narnia')));
```

Comment: Any particular reason you have arrays within an array instead of just tags:['narnia','aslan','winter'] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hussain mentioned in comments - you might want to revise that document structure as seems like you're storing unnecessary arrays.

Otherwise, what you're trying to do could be done with an `$and` statement (example without the nested arrays):

```
PRIMARY> db.wardrobe.find({ $and: [ { tags: "narnia" }, { tags: "tugboat" } ] })
//returns nothing

PRIMARY> db.wardrobe.find({ $and: [ { tags: "narnia" }, { tags: "winter" } ] })
//returns { "_id" : ObjectId("521067a48202463b88c2a0c9"), "tags" : [ "narnia", "aslan", "winter", "heaven" ] }
```

In PHP:

```
//With your nested arrays:
$filter = array(
   '$and' => array( 
      array('tags' => array('narnia') ), 
      array('tags' => array('aslan') )
   )
);

//With a simple array:
$filter = array(
   '$and' => array( 
      array('tags' => 'narnia'), 
      array('tags' => 'aslan')
   )
);

$mongoClient->selectCollection('cwlewis', 'wardrobe')->find( $filter );
```

Comment: I managed to solve with this $filter['tags'] = array('$in' => array(array(array('narnia'),array('aslan'))))

Comment: @poembase - I don't think that query in your comment works, unless you changed your document structure...